# About containers: Suppose that we have two applications running, on two different containers, bound to the same port 80

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Suppose that we have two applications running, on two different containers bound to port 80. Is it possible to expose both of these applications on port 80 of the guest machine?

I think the answer might be yes since each container runs in an isolated network namespace so everyone can listen on the same port and they will not conflict (in the simple case of two containers running in the same port, but with the introduction of a guest machine I am in doubt)

Comment: What does "expose" mean here?  You tagged this question with several different technologies; is there a specific environment you're working in?

Comment: I think by exposed he meant "put them both"

Comment: In this case the specific technology is containers, the subject I am doing is Cloud Platforms, where we see an introduction to cloud computing concepts, a little bit of kubernetes and Openstack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly fine, as you write, the containers will have their own network namespace.